# How to set up a GIT server to accept multiple users and password auth like GitHub

Tags: git, ubuntu, git-remote

I am trying to build a service that acts a lot like GitHub, except for a different vertical. I want users to be able to sign up for an account, create a repository, and then be able to push to it via their local machines just like GitHub/BitBucket etc.

Online I only see resources on how to set up Git to use public-private key pairs, but GitHub and related services do not require this. Instead it is simply a matter of logging into the user's account via the Terminal with username and password.

I looked into Gitolite: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html which looked promising.

Has anyone configured a similar environment? How might I go about this without requiring the user to set up public-private keys, and instead just use their account credentials?

Answer (score 0):

GitLab is very similar to GitHub and can be self-hosted.
https://about.gitlab.com/

Update:
GitLab offers a commercial version, but the community version is open source (MIT license).

Comment: second this.  I run GitLab in-house and we love it.  Give GitLab a look.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This tool is paid though, and not really what I'm looking for. This product that I'm building is meant to have public signups too like GitHub, so that would be enormously expensive.